# Проблема с mikrotik API?

Tags: bash, api, mikrotik

Пытаюсь реализовать часть API Mikrotik на bash, проблема на этапе login.
Приведу написанное как есть:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/172.16.55.1/8728
passwd='_mY\#Pazzw0rd\{'

chr () {
        printf \\$(printf %o $1)
}

sread () {
        response=`timeout 1 cat <&3 | tr -d '\0' `
        challenge=`echo -ne $response | gawk -F"=" '{ print $3 }' | xxd -r -p`
        echo $challenge
        zero=`chr 0`
        md=`echo -ne $zero$passwd$challenge | md5sum | gawk '{ print $1 }'`
        #cmd='/login=name=admin=response=00'$md
        cmd1='/login'
        cmd2='=name=admin'
        cmd3='=response=00'$md
}

wLogin () {
        sread
        #wWord $cmd
        wWord $cmd1
        wWord $cmd2
        wWord $cmd3
}

sclose () {
        exec 3<&-
        exec 3>&-
}

len () {
        echo -ne ${#1}
}

wWord () {
        echo $1
        wLen $1 
        echo -ne $1 >&3
        wLen  
}


wLen () {
        echo `len $1`
        chr `len $1` >&3
}
```

Использовать так:

```
source api.sh
wWord /login
sread
wLogin
```

tcpdump'ом вижу в ответ:
!fatal.not logged in

В качестве примера смотрел: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:API_Python3

Comment: Я в питонячьем языке шибко не разумею, но глянув [csharp реализацию](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_in_C_Sharp) вижу, что у вас вообще и близко не реализован hash - вы берёте md5, а там сложнее всё.

Comment: А я в C#, но вопрос задам уточняющий, что происходит в:
Send("=response=00" + EncodePassword(password, hash), true);
Конкретно, что делает EncodePassword (password, hash) - зачем два аргумента?

Comment: А по-моему тут очень напрашивается *man curl*

Comment: zOMG, этот код совсем не на питоне написан, что они у себя приводят... Туда лучше вообще не смотреть, а читать вместо этого спецификацию протокола.

Comment: Не понял, причем тут curl?

Comment: К сожалению, никакой спецификации я не нашел (может плохо искал). Пример по ссылке не единственный, что я смотрел. Mikrotik::API на perl тоже изучал, в принципе, там все тоже самое, только.... по-перловому.